# Problema com acentuação ao gerar PDF com dompdf

Tags: php, html, acentuação, utf-8, dompdf

Estou gerando um relatório em PDF usando a API dompdf, e as palavras que contém acentuação não estão sendo exibidas corretamente.

Coloquei a tag charset='utf-8' dentro do head, mas não resolve o problema

```
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
```

---

Nos elementos php se eu fizer:

```
<?php echo utf8_decode($variavel); ?>
```

O conteúdo é exibido corretamente com a acentuação...

*Mas os elementos HTML continuam com problema de acentuação...

> **Exemplo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**

```
<?php
ob_start('geraPDF'); 
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>

    <style>
        p{
            border:1px solid black;
            box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #ccc;
            width:90%;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>

     </head>

    <body>

        <b>Empresa: </b><?php echo utf8_decode($empresas); ?><br>

        <b>Data: </b><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($dt)); ?><br>

        <b>Nº da OS: </b><?php echo $os; ?><br>

        <b>Nº Orçamento: </b><?php $norcamento; ?><br><br>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
// Importa arquivo de config da classe DOMPDF
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

/**
 *  Função ob_get_clean obtém conteúdo que está no buffer
 *  e exclui o buffer de saída atual.
 *  http://br1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-get-clean.php 
 */
$html = ob_get_clean(); 
$pdf = new DOMPDF();
$pdf->load_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream(date('d/m/Y').'_orcamento.pdf', array('Attachment'=>0));
?>
```

O resultado não sai como o esperado no pdf...o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Já tentou setar o header? `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')`.

Comment: Acredito que vai encontrar o que [precisa aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136067/dompdf-special-characters).

Comment: É isso, problema resolvido. Muito obrigado! @Bruno Wego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro tente adicionar ao PHP o cabeçalho:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')
```

Caso está solução não funcione, edite o arquivo **dompdf_config.inc.php**:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
```

A resposta acima tem como base uma [resposta no stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136067/dompdf-special-characters#answer-17461636) internacional.