# DomPDF retornando acentos como ponto de interrogação

Tags: dompdf

Estou usando a versão 8.2 do `DomDPF` só que os caracteres especiais ficam como "?".

Já tentei usar a solução [deste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86332/problema-com-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-gerar-pdf-com-dompdf) só que não tem um arquivo **dompdf_config.inc.php** aqui. Nem adicionando o código (`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')`) funciona.

Comment: Tente antes de passar seu código html para o dompdf aplicá-lo na função `utf8_decode($html)` como na resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084057/9671639

Comment: Ainda fica com os pontos de interrogação